# Why isn't Set -> Set : Set?

Tags: types, coq

In Coq as a mathematician I would have expected that

```
Set -> Set : Set
```

but I guess this is because my mathematician hat is on. What can I do to get this to work?

Should I be thinking of Set differently and use a different kind of Set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I guess this is because my mathematician hat is on

Perhaps you need your set theorist hat.  We can build an injection `Set -> (Set -> Set)` by sending each `Set` to the constant function returning that `Set`, i.e., `fun S => (fun _ => S)`.  If `(Set -> Set) : Set`, then we would have a set ( namely, `(Set -> Set)`) which contains all sets.  This would be an issue, because then you could follow Russell's paradox and ask about the set of all sets that don't contain themselves, and you could ask whether or not this set contained itself, which is absurd.  Thus you cannot have `(Set -> Set) : Set`.  (See also `Coq.Logic.Hurkens` for formalized versions of a variant of this theorem.)

Since `(Set -> Set)` is too big to be a `Set`, it lives at the next level up, in `Type`.  It may be helpful to `Set Printing Universes`.  In general, we have `Type@{i} : Type@{i+1}`.

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it I think i meant a : Set -> b : Set being a set. I think i was just tired when writing this question. Thank you for your enlightening discussion however.